# How to convert empty arrays to nulls?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below dataframe and i need to convert empty arrays to null.

```
+----+---------+-----------+
|  id|count(AS)|count(asdr)|
+----+---------+-----------+
|1110| [12, 45]|   [50, 55]|     
|1111|       []|         []|    
|1112| [45, 46]|   [50, 50]|   
|1113|       []|         []|
+----+---------+-----------+
```

i have tried below code which is not working.

```
df.na.fill("null").show()
```

expected output should be

```
+----+---------+-----------+
|  id|count(AS)|count(asdr)|
+----+---------+-----------+
|1110| [12, 45]|   [50, 55]|     
|1111|     NUll|       NUll|    
|1112| [45, 46]|   [50, 50]|   
|1113|     NUll|       NUll|
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace empty strings with None/null values in DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287886/replace-empty-strings-with-none-null-values-in-dataframe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your given `dataframe`, you can simply do the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("count(AS)", F.when((F.size(F.col("count(AS)")) == 0), F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col("count(AS)"))) \
    .withColumn("count(asdr)", F.when((F.size(F.col("count(asdr)")) == 0), F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col("count(asdr)"))).show()
```

You should have output `dataframe` as

```
+----+---------+-----------+
|  id|count(AS)|count(asdr)|
+----+---------+-----------+
|1110| [12, 45]|   [50, 55]|
|1111|     null|       null|
|1112| [45, 46]|   [50, 50]|
|1113|     null|       null|
+----+---------+-----------+
```

**Updated**

In case you have more than two array columns and you want to apply the above logic dynamically, you can use the following logic

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
for c in df.dtypes:
    if "array" in c[1]:
        df = df.withColumn(c[0], F.when((F.size(F.col(c[0])) == 0), F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col(c[0])))
df.show()
```

Here,
`df.dtypes` would give you array of tuples with column name and datatype. As for the dataframe in the question it would be

```
[('id', 'bigint'), ('count(AS)', 'array<bigint>'), ('count(asdr)', 'array<bigint>')]
```

`withColumn` is applied to only *array* columns `("array" in c[1])` where `F.size(F.col(c[0])) == 0` is the condition checking for `when` function which checks for the size of the array. if the condition is true i.e. empty array then None is populated else original value is populated. The loop is applied to all the array columns.

Comment: Thank you for your input.My  array columns may increase so I am looking for dynamic process in pyspark. so that i wont be going back to code to update when the columns with empty arrays increases. please let me know if there is any dynamic process

Comment: @Alice, I have updated my answer, :) I hope its helpful

Comment: This is great, thanks :) can you please explain what "c" reffers to... and what exactly df.dtypes is doing

Comment: can you explain the functionality of code for better understanding

Comment: @Alice, done the explanation part too. let me know if there's still confusions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. one small clarification. c[1] and c[0] refers to column index? or c(0) is column name and c(1) is datatype ?

Comment: c[0] is the column name and c[1] is the dataType .

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me

Comment: how this works when nested Arrays? @Alice

Answer (score 4):

I don't think thats possible with `na.fill`, but this should work for you. The code converts all empty ArrayType-columns to null and keeps the other columns as they are:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (110, Seq.empty[Int]),
  (111, Seq(1,2,3))
).toDF("id","arr")

// get names of array-type columns
val arrColsNames = df.schema.fields.filter(f => f.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]).map(_.name)

// map all empty arrays to nulls
val emptyArraysAsNulls = arrColsNames.map(n => when(size(col(n))>0,col(n)).as(n))

// non-array-type columns, keep them as they are
val keepCols = df.columns.filterNot(arrColsNames.contains).map(col)

df
  .select((keepCols ++ emptyArraysAsNulls):_*)
  .show()

+---+---------+
| id|      arr|
+---+---------+
|110|     null|
|111|[1, 2, 3]|
+---+---------+
```

Comment: i am using the same functions in pyspark and this is the error i am getting  
arrColsNames = df1.schema.fields.filter(lambda x: x.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]).map(_.name) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: @Alice Sorry, I missed that you are working with Python, my solution works for scala. Maybe this could work in python : `df1.schema.fields.filter(lambda x: x.dataType.typeName == "array").map(_.name)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for the `size` of the array type column. Like:

```
df.show()
+----+---+
|  id|arr|
+----+---+
|1110| []|
+----+---+

df.withColumn("arr", when(size(col("arr")) == 0 , lit(None)).otherwise(col("arr") ) ).show()

+----+----+
|  id| arr|
+----+----+
|1110|null|
+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, in your code you have taken "arr" column but here i may have many columns which contains empty arrays. so in actual production hard coding is not a best practice right. dont we have function that converts all empty arrays to "null" like df.na,fill() which is not working in this case

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy solution like `df.na.fill` here. One way would be to loop over all relevant columns and replace values where appropriate. Example using `foldLeft` in scala:

```scala
val columns = df.schema.filter(_.dataType.typeName == "array").map(_.name)

val df2 = columns.foldLeft(df)((acc, colname) => acc.withColumn(colname, 
    when(size(col(colname)) === 0, null).otherwise(col(colname))))
```

First, all columns of array type is extracted and then these are iterated through. Since the `size` function is only defined for columns of array type this is a necessary step (and avoids looping over all columns).

Using the dataframe:

```
+----+--------+-----+
|  id|    col1| col2|
+----+--------+-----+
|1110|[12, 11]|   []|
|1111|      []| [11]|
|1112|   [123]|[321]|
+----+--------+-----+
```

The result is as follows:

```
+----+--------+-----+
|  id|    col1| col2|
+----+--------+-----+
|1110|[12, 11]| null|
|1111|    null| [11]|
|1112|   [123]|[321]|
+----+--------+-----+
```

Comment: arrColsNames = df1.schema.fields.filter(lambda x: x.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]).map(_.name)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter' this is the error i am getting

Comment: @Alice: In python it should look something like, `arrColsNames  = [c.name for c in df1.schema.fields if c.dataType.isInstanceOf(ArrayType)]`. I can't try it out myself right now but hopefully it will help you.

Comment: ERROR  ----  arrColsNames = [c.name for c in df1.schema.fields if c.dataType.isInstanceOf(ArrayType)]
AttributeError: 'StringType' object has no attribute 'isInstanceOf'

Comment: @Alice: Try `arrColsNames = [c.name for c in df1.schema if c.dataType == 'array']`. Should work assuming the same names as in scala.

Comment: can you please look into this syntax as well in pyspark
"val df2 = columns.foldLeft(df)((acc, colname) => acc.withColumn(colname, 
    when(size(col(colname)) === 0, null).otherwise(col(colname))))"

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `selectExpr`:

```
df_filled = df.selectExpr(
    "id",
    "if(size(column1)<=0, null, column1)",
    "if(size(column2)<=0, null, column2)",
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.withColumn("arr", when(size(col("arr")) == 0, lit(None)).otherwise(col("arr") ) ).show()
```

Please keep in mind, it's also not work in pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

By taking Ramesh Maharajans above solution as reference. I have found an another way of solution using UDFs. hope this helps you for multiple rules on your dataframe.

df

```
|store|   1|   2|   3|
+-----+----+----+----+
|  103|[90]|  []|  []|
|  104|  []|[67]|[90]|
|  101|[34]|  []|  []|
|  102|[35]|  []|  []|
+-----+----+----+----+
```

use below code, import `import pyspark.sql.functions as psf`
This code works in pyspark

```
def udf1(x :list):
    if x==[]: return "null"
    else: return x
udf2 = udf(udf1, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

for c in df.dtypes:
    if "array" in c[1]:
        df=df.withColumn(c[0],udf2(psf.col(c[0])))
df.show()
```

output

```
|store|   1|   2|   3|
+-----+----+----+----+
|  103|[90]|null|null|
|  104|null|[67]|[90]|
|  101|[34]|null|null|
|  102|[35]|null|null|
+-----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks working perfectly fine. yes this helps me to apply multiple rules on my data frame.