# Spark Dataframe size check on columns does not work as expected using vararg and if else - Scala

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, if-statement, size

I do not want to use foldLeft or withColumn with when over all columns in a dataframe, but want a select  as per https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015, embellished with an if else statement and cols with vararg. All I want is to replace an empty array column in a Spark dataframe using Scala. I am using size but it never computes the zero (0) correctly.

```
val resDF2 = aggDF.select(cols.map { col =>
         ( if (size(aggDF(col)) == 0) lit(null) else aggDF(col) ).as(s"$col") 
                                   }: _*)
```

**if (size(aggDF(col)) == 0) lit(null)**   does not work here functionally, but it does run and **size(aggDF(col))** returns the correct length if I return that.

I am wondering what the silly issue is. Must be something I am obviously overlooking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if-else` won't work with DataFrame API, these are for Scala logical expressions. With DataFrames you need `when`/`otherwise`:

```
val resDF2 = aggDF.select(cols.map { col => ( when(size(aggDF(col)) === 0,lit(null)).otherwise(aggDF(col))).as(s"$col") }: _*)
```

This can further be simplified because `when` without `otherwise` automatically returns `null` (i.e. `otherwise(lit(null))` is the default):

```
val resDF2 = aggDF.select(cols.map { col => when(size(aggDF(col)) > 0,aggDF(col)).as(s"$col") }: _*)
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48074218/1138523

Comment: OK, thx. interesting in that it runs (incorrectly). I could not find this, but merry XMAS.